# Final methods in HashMap Class

Tags: java, hashmap, final

I was just going through the source code of HashMap in openJDK8 and wanted to understand that although the class TreeMap(static final class TreeNode) is declared as final, there are methods in the class that are declared as final - wanted to understand the significance of that.

since the class is marked as final, the class cannot be extended, and so its methods cannot be over ridden, I have gone through the oracle docs , that says sometimes the methods that are called from constructor needs to be declared as final, but there are some methods that are not called from constructor still they are declared final. So can any one please help me understand.

Below link has complete code:

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java

Comment: HashMap is extended so it's not a final class, but some methods are made final so their behaviour can be assumed.

Comment: my question is, when a class is final( for ex. the TreeNode class in HashMap), all its methods become final, so what is the significance of making its methods final again.

Comment: I think the reason is purely stylistic, just to make it crystal-clear to the reader of the code.

Answer (score 0):

final keyword used in method declaration is for different purpose vs final keyword used in class declaration.

**final method** : -You can declare some or all of a class's methods final. You use the final keyword in a method declaration to indicate that the method cannot be overridden by subclasses. The Object class does this—a number of its methods are final.

**final class** :- you can also declare an entire class final. A class that is declared final cannot be subclassed. This is particularly useful, for example, when creating an immutable class like the String class.

Source:-https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/final.html

Comment: my question is, when a class is final( for ex. the TreeNode class in HashMap), all its methods become final, so what is the significance of making its methods final again.

Comment: okay, once the class is final, that class cannot be extended, so why are we declaring some methods inside the class as final, I have gone through the link that you have given, some of the methods are not called from constructor, still they are declared final.

Comment: Thank you, once the class is marked as final, the class cannot be extended, and so its methods cannot be over ridden, I have gone through the link that you have provided, that says sometimes the methods that are called from constructor needs to be declared as final, but there are some methods that are not called from constructor still they are declared final. so I wanted to understand that

Comment: @Vignesh after searching on net, still i cant figure out why some methods in HashMap declared explicitly as final. BUT java doesnt restrict to do it either, like you can declare **public abstract** explicitly in methods  of interface despite they are implicitly **public abstract**.

Comment: Thank you, even I'm not able to understand, so just wanted to confirm if there are any reasons.

Answer (score 0):

"final" keyword is used in a method declaration to indicate that the method cannot be overridden by subclasses.

In addition to that, there are some performance advantages of it:

"final methods can be inlined after being loaded into the JVM, because at that point the JVM knows definitely that the method is final. So compilers that operate after class loading, such as JIT compilers, can take advantage of final methods. Consequently, methods declared final could have some performance benefit."

However despite its performance advantage, the most important usage aim is "clear design". It is used in HashMap to indicate those methods will not be overriden by the subclasses since their implementation is guaranteed in that way

Comment: my question is, when a class is final( for ex. the TreeNode class in HashMap), all its methods become final, so what is the significance of making its methods final again.